# Adding an Iterator to a Collection

Tags: java

Below is my learning objective.  I got it started, but I don't really know where to go from here to implement the program in main.  I would appreciate any help!

Objective:

- Add an Iterator object to the card collection
- Iterators are added to collections by creating a private inner class.
- You may use any of the inner class types that are appropriate
- Enumerators and Iterators use a large number to determine when the collection changes.
- Implement the correct methods, interfaces, and extend the appropriate classes for a class consistent with the Java API.

  ```
  public class CardCollection {

  private ArrayList<Card> cards;
  private ArrayList<Note> notes;

  public CardCollection() { //constructor initializes the two arraylists
    cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
   }

  private class Card implements Iterable<Card> { //create the inner class

      public Iterator<Card> iterator() { //create the Iterator for Card
          return cards.iterator();
      }
  }

  private class Note implements Iterable<Note> { //create the inner class

      public Iterator<Note> iterator() { //create the Iterator for Note
          return notes.iterator();
      }

  }

  public Card cards() {
      return new Card();
   }

   public Note notes() {
       return new Note();
   }

   public void add(Card card) {
       cards.add(card);
   }

   public void add(Note note) {
       notes.add(note);
   }

  }
  ```

Comment: It's very, very unusual -- and probably not what you mean -- to have a class `Foo` implement `Iterable<Foo>`.  You should make sure you're keeping track of which things are supposed to be multiple `Foo`s, and which is supposed to be a single `Foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two concepts here that I think you may be mixing up.  An object if Iterable if you can iterate over some internal elements.

So if I have a shopping cart with items in it, I can iterate over my groceries.

```
public class ShoppingCart implements Iterable<GroceryItem>
{
   public Iterator<GroceryItem> iterator()
   {
      // return an iterator
   }
}
```

So in order to use this functionality, I need to provide an Iterator.  In your code example, you are reusing the iterators from ArrayList.  From your exercise description, I believe you need to implement one yourself.  For example:

```
public class GroceryIterator implements Iterator<GroceryItem>
{
  private GroceryItem[] items;
  private int currentElement = 0;

  public GroceryIterator(GroceryItem[] items)
  {
    this.items = items;
  }

  public GroceryItem next() // implement this
  public void remove() // implement this
  public boolean hasNext() // implement this
}
```

So I sorta gave you a hint with the constructor/member variables.  After you make this class, your Iterable class (my ShoppingCart) will return my new iterator.

The assignment recommends using a private inner class for your custom Iterator.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

- Iterable objects are usually collections. That suits better with CardCollection than with Card
- Public methods cards() and notes() are returning types Card and Note which are private. I think those are meant to be public.
- I think methods cards() and notes() are meant to return the iterator.